# Convert reportviewer data to xml

Tags: xml, reportviewer

How can we convert data displayed in a reportviewer to an xml file?

Comment: I voted to close as "not a real question". Questions should be detailed and specific as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the .Render method, with the first parameter (format) equal to "XML".  Just like in the examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport(VS.80).aspx -- except use "XML" instead of "Excel" as the format (and of course something like .xml instead of .xsl as the format for the file you write;-).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running ReportViewer in local mode, your XML file is the RDLC file.
Just open the RDLC file in a XML viewer.